# Running Python 2.7 projects on Python 3.x? (TIA package-related issue)

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, bloomberg

I'm trying to use a github project (TIA), which is dependent on Python 2.7. However, all of the scripts I'm using in the main project are written to run on Anaconda 3 (Python 3.x).

Is there a way for me to run TIA on Python 3.x, even though it says its 2.7 dependent? TIA pulls financial data from Bloomberg's API, and what I'm trying to do is hand that data off to my Python 3.x scripts.

Appreciate any insight on how I should be accomplishing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for me to run TIA on Python 3.x, even though it says
>   its 2.7 dependent?

Short answer: no.

Long(er) answer: yes, but you'll have to either adapt the source-code yourself, find someone who has already done it (maybe there is some Python3 compatible fork on Git?). Or you might run python 2.7 to execute the code and write a Python3 script that transforms the output into an acceptable form.

If you are willing to update the source code you could of course use Python2.7's `2to3` module, of which the documentation is found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html). Do not expect it to generate a flawless result however, but it might smoothen the ride..